# how to create a table in React Draft WYSIWYG

Tags: rich-text-editor

how do I create a table in React Draft WYSIWYG, I'm trying to create a rich text editor but I need to include a button so the user can include table in the text editor. how best can I achieve this in React Draft WYSIWYG.?

Answer (score 1):

if you have not getting the options for table so you can you  table plugin using

`draft-js-table-plugin`

Comment: oh okay cool.. will check it out. but do you have any articles or videos which can help me understand it?

Comment: I think that plug in isn't available

Comment: i think you can go thorugh this https://www.npmjs.com/package/draft-js-table-plugin